# Cannot Convert Implicit Types

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, implicit-conversion

I am trying to program a game in unity however the following lines are having an error in them

```
public TriggerAnim Instance;
Instance = GetComponentsInChildren <TriggerAnim> ();
```

TriggerAnim is a script attached to a child within my hirarchy.
however it is genrating an error message as ->

```
 error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `TriggerAnim[]' to `TriggerAnim'
```

Please suggest any possible reasons why this error is popping up.
The Programming language is c#. 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: you are trying to convert an array of TriggerAnim to a single Anim. Maybe using system.Linq and FirstOrDefault()

Comment: I would suggest reading some of the `Unity` documentations as well as learning and understand some of the basic coding concepts. If you do not understand what it is your are coding and why the error is happening as well as when it tell you in the error what the problem is.. I would suggest brushing up on some basics in C# for example the difference between a `string` "Hello" and a `string[]` `{ "hello", "world"}` respectfully speaking [C# Basic Coding Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are calling is returning an array of 'TriggerAnim' objects. You would need either

```
public TriggerAnim[] Instance = GetComponentsChildren<TriggerAnim>();
```

or

```
// This would select the First TriggerAnim object depending on some condition you must specify
public TriggerAnim Instance = GetComponentsChildren<TriggerAnim>().First( x = > ...);
```

What you choose would depend on the use case.

Answer (score 1):

The method `GetComponentsInChildren' returns an array. If you want only one child component use

```
GetComponentInChild<TriggerAnim>();
```

If you instead want to store the array in a variable, use

`public TriggerAnim[] Instance` instead of `public TriggerAnim Instance`